Как работает редирект для SPA приложения на стороне сервера
Всем привет!
Допустим у меня есть SPA приложение, весь роутинг происходит на фронте. Например есть главная страница по пути '/', и страница личного кабинета по пути '/profile'. Если переходить по ссылкам на страницах, то все нормально - url меняется, по факту никаких переходов не происходит, конструирование страниц происходит на клиентской стороне. Но если пользователь руками ввел в адресную строку например 'https://mySite.ru/profile' браузер пытается обратиться по этому адресу. Я знаю, что на стороне сервера можно сделать редирект с любого запроса и переадресовать куда нужно (например с помощью файла .htaccess). Понятно, что если это SPA, то нужно вернуть индексную страницу. Но каким образом на стороне клиента "понять", что пользователь хотел обратиться не на главную страницу, а на /profile ?
Или я вообще что-то не так понимаю?

Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.
